# How do I create a sliding menu in appcelerator titanium?

Tags: menu, titanium, appcelerator, drawer

I want to make a menu that opens up from the left side, that has an image at the top, and then a few sections that redirects to a page each. I have searched online, some post a github link and when I go there I freeze. No idea what I am asupposed to do? Should I install something? Is that a sample code? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the third party module for this, their are some in the market. I'll give example of the one I use, or else you can search for some other with key work **Drawer in Titanium**.

> For Android : https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer/tree/master/android

```
var homeScreen = Alloy.createController("homeScreen").getView();

var NappDrawerModule = require('dk.napp.drawer');
Alloy.Globals.drawer = NappDrawerModule.createDrawer({
    fullscreen : false,
    leftWindow : Alloy.createController('leftMenu').getView(),
    centerWindow : homeScreen,
    fading : 0.2, // 0-1
    parallaxAmount : 0.2, //0-1
    exitOnClose : true,
    shadowWidth : "5dp",
    leftDrawerWidth : "280dp",
    animationMode : NappDrawerModule.ANIMATION_NONE,
    closeDrawerGestureMode : NappDrawerModule.CLOSE_MODE_NONE,
    openDrawerGestureMode : NappDrawerModule.OPEN_MODE_NONE,
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT]
});

Alloy.Globals.drawer.addEventListener("didChangeOffset", function(e) {
    //Ti.API.info("didChangeOffset: " + e.offset);
});
Alloy.Globals.drawer.addEventListener("android:back", function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('currentWindow : ' + Alloy.Globals.currentWindow);
    if (Alloy.Globals.currentWindow != null) {
        return;
    }
});

Alloy.Globals.drawer.addEventListener("windowDidOpen", function(e) {

    if (e.window == NappDrawerModule.LEFT_WINDOW) {
        Ti.API.info("windowDidOpen - LEFT DRAWER");
    } else if (e.window == NappDrawerModule.RIGHT_WINDOW) {
        Ti.API.info("windowDidOpen - RIGHT DRAWER");
    }

});

Alloy.Globals.drawer.addEventListener("open", function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Drawer Open');
});

Alloy.Globals.drawer.addEventListener("windowDidClose", function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("windowDidClose");
});

// lets open it
Alloy.Globals.drawer.open();
```

> For iOS : https://github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu

```
Alloy.Globals.SlideWindow = Alloy.createController("leftMenu");
var homeWindow = Alloy.createController("homeScreen").getView();

var NappSlideMenu = require('dk.napp.slidemenu');

var window = NappSlideMenu.createSlideMenuWindow({
    centerWindow : homeWindow,
    leftWindow : Alloy.Globals.SlideWindow.getView(),
    leftLedge : (Alloy.Globals.iPad) ? 170 : 70,
    parallaxAmount : 0.2,
});

Alloy.Globals.window = window;

window.addEventListener("viewWillOpen", function(e) {
});

window.addEventListener("viewWillClose", function(e) {
});

exports.openLeft = function() {
    window.toggleLeftView();
};

exports.openRight = function() {
    window.toggleRightView();
};

window.open();
```

> **Note :** `leftMenu` and `homeScreen` for android is a `View`, but for iOS it is a `Window`.

**Good Luck, Cheers**